# Service 'laravel.test' failed to build : Build failed [MAC]

Tags: laravel, docker

I am trying to setup a new Laravel project on MAC Big Sur [with sailup/docker], but i am getting the following error. **The laravel.test build fails**.

I am following all the step by step instruction for MAC Installation from: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#getting-started-on-macos

Please help.

```
#7 293.9 Get:127 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe amd64 gosu amd64 1.12-1build1 [745 kB]
#7 295.9 Fetched 42.0 MB in 3min 51s (182 kB/s)
#7 295.9 E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng1.6/libpng-dev_1.6.37-3build3_amd64.deb  Connection timed out [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
#7 295.9 E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update     && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2     && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg     && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg     && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf     && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E5267A6C     && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C300EE8C     && echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y php8.0-cli php8.0-dev        php8.0-pgsql php8.0-sqlite3 php8.0-gd        php8.0-curl php8.0-memcached        php8.0-imap php8.0-mysql php8.0-mbstring        php8.0-xml php8.0-zip php8.0-bcmath php8.0-soap        php8.0-intl php8.0-readline php8.0-pcov        php8.0-msgpack php8.0-igbinary php8.0-ldap        php8.0-redis php8.0-swoole     && php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer     && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -     && apt-get install -y nodejs     && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -     && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y yarn     && apt-get install -y mysql-client     && apt-get install -y postgresql-client     && apt-get -y autoremove     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*]: exit code: 100
ERROR: Service 'laravel.test' failed to build : Build failed
```

Comment: Laravel Sail is not supported on M1/Apple Silicon Macs (see this issue on Sail https://github.com/laravel/sail/issues/104#issuecomment-821042352).

While the ecosystem catches up, it should be noted that the recommend "quick start" method does not work on this hardware, and an alternative should be presented.

Comment: Can you leverage the m1 setup in valet? https://dev.to/ibrarturi/mac-m1-setup-for-local-development-with-laravel-valet-2lmk

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Try to:

1. uninstall docker
2. restart Mac
3. [download](https://www.docker.com/get-started/) and installed the lates version of docker
4. sail up your laravel project.